# Bash not setting line wrap correctly

Tags: bash

Here's my ps1 variable:

```
export PS1='\e[33;1m\u@\h\]: \e[31m\W\e[0m\e[0;32m$(parse_git_branch)\e[0m$\] '
```

Where `parse_git_branch` is a function that shows what branch I'm currently on in git, such as (master).

I've also set this in my .bashrc

```
stty columns 500
```

The behavior is really weird - in VS code if I make my integrated terminal really small, the line wrapping works correctly. If it's above a certain size, it starts overwriting itself on the same line.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**edit**

Ben was correct below - I had to make sure the escape characters matched up and wrapped the entire thing in brackets. This seems to work:

```
export PS1='\[\e[33;1m\u@\h\]: \e[31m\W\e \e[0;32m$(parse_git_branch)\] \]\e[0m$\]\] \]'
```

Comment: You have to escape all non-printing sequences with `\[...\]`, but you only have the closing `\]` or nothing at all.

Comment: `\u` et al.  aren't really non-printing sequences. `bash` knows how long the result will be, so they (and the literal character `@`) need to be left *out* of the `\[...\]` groups.